# FormGeneratorModule plugin in Netbeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java

I'm using java version 1.8.0_111 and Netbeans IDE 8.2 and i want to install FormGeneratorModule plugin in Netbeans but the folowing messege appears to me :

Some plugins require plugin javax.jmi.reflect to be installed.
The plugin javax.jmi.reflect is requested in version 1.7.1.  The following plugin is affected:       FormGeneratorModule 
Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.api.mdr to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.api.mdr is requested in version 1.4.1.  The following plugin is affected:       FormGeneratorModule 
Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.jmi.javamodel to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.jmi.javamodel is requested in version 1.21.1.  The following plugin is affected:       FormGeneratorModule 
Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.javacore to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.javacore is requested in version 1.18.1.2.2.  The following plugin is affected:       FormGeneratorModule 
Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.jmiutils to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.jmiutils is requested in version 1.5.1.2.  The following plugin is affected:       FormGeneratorModule 
Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.mdr to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.mdr is requested in version 1.5.1.2.2.  The following plugin is affected:       FormGeneratorModule  Some plugins not installed to avoid potential installation problems.al installation problems.